# Is there a repository for pgadmin plugins?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've been using PostgreSQL with PGAdmin III for a while now and it's been bugging me that there is a plugins menu option that is empty. I've Googled some and found a plugin here and there but I wanted to know if there was a repository I was missing out on?

If you don't know of a repo but are aware of additional plugins please also let me know about them.

Answer (score 2):

Your best place would be pgfoundry. But you won't find much. Doesn't look like many plugins are available.